# @font-face doesn't work (in any type.)

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, truetype, font-family

For a school project I'm obligated to use a fonts folder instead of just the Google URL, so here's what I did.

```
@font-face{
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        src: url('../fonts/OpenSans-Regular.eot');
        src: url('../fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('../fonts/OpenSans-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('../fonts/OpenSans-Regular.woff'), format('woff'),
             url('../fonts/OpenSans-Regular.svg'), format('svg'); 
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
}
```

I have the same blocks of code for the bold/italic version. I guess I'm using it the right way.

```
@media (min-width: 769px){
body{
        font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    }
}
```

Removing the `../` doesn't work, Removing the `@media` doesn't work either. Any sugestions?

I'm using Chrome, so it should work at least for me.

Comment: Are there any errors in your console, or does the font fail quietly?

Comment: truetypes fonts should be supported by early versions of chrome , and I see no syntactic errors in your css declarations, could you show your paths (where css and fonts are stored relative to a common ancestor dir) ? Also if you are not already specifying other fonts types for firefox or explorer consider using http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: If your .css file is under your CSS folder as well as your fonts folder then this kind of path should work: `/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf` Notice that the difference from your OP comment is that the forward slash is retained but the two periods dropped. The two periods mean "go up a folder level" then look for a fonts folder.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/a746c9496908670d9bef76286b56322d
These are the paths.
I already editted the code so it should work with IE etc. but still doesn't change anything.

Comment: @ThibaultFouquaert you should modify the question instead of pointing to external resources.

Comment: anyway the paths are fine, the second thing that comes to my mind is, are the @font-face rules placed before the media query? and what about permissions on the fonts dir (look at web server log if you can) ?

Comment: I solved the problem...
suddenly i tought i didn't add <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"> to my html file...
stupid, i know... but i'm still learning and not very good at this.
Thanks for your time anyway!
@PaulSasik:sorry, i hitted enter while i meant shift-enter...

Comment: @ThibaultFouquaert: Please do share!

Comment: it's also fine to answer your own question, as an actual answer to your post!

Comment: Agreed with @DRC: It might feel trivial but please do answer your own question. Remember, if it might help another developer down the road... That's what SO is for.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Suddenly I thought, I didn't add `<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">` to my html file. Stupid, I know but I'm still learning and not very good at this.

Thanks for your time anyway!

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @JasonAller That would not be appropriate.  Answers should not go into questions.